# Rotation of binary number in C

Tags: c

I have an issue i can't solve. The code below should get a number from the user and a number of rotations. The code should calculate the number after the rotations. For negative number of rotations the code should rotate the number left and for positive number of rotation the code should rotate the number right.

For example: for the input x=1010111011111011

my_rotate(x, -3) will return 0111010111011111 
my_rotate(x, 3) will return 0111011111011101

Here is the code i wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>


unsigned short my_rotate(unsigned short, char);


int main()
{
    unsigned short num, res;
    char rotations;


    printf("\nPlease enter a number and number of rotations\n");
    scanf("%hu %d", &num, &rotations);


    res = my_rotate(num, rotations);

    return 0;
}

unsigned short my_rotate(unsigned short a, char b)
{
   unsigned short bitsNum = sizeof(unsigned short) * 8;
   unsigned short temp1, temp2, result;


   if(b == 0)
      return a;

   else if(b < 0)
   {
    temp1 = a << (bitsNum + b);
    temp2 = a >> (-b);
    result = temp1 + temp2;
   }

   else  /* b > 0 */
   {        
    temp1 = (a >> (bitsNum - (unsigned short)b));
    temp2 = (a << (unsigned short)b);   
    result = temp1 + temp2; 
   }

  return result;

}
```

I always get 0 as a result and i don't know why. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: There's no need for temporary variables. Just do the math inline, as in `return (a << (bitsNum + b)) +  a >> (-b))`

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings.  A good compiler will warn about  `char rotations;
number of rotations\n"); 
    scanf("%hu %d", &num, &rotations);`.  Maybe with `warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 3 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]` Save you and us time.

Comment: BTW, Good use of _unsigned_ types for the data to rotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

in *main* :

> ```
> unsigned short num, res;
> char rotations;
>
>
> printf("\nPlease enter a number and number of rotations\n");
> scanf("%hu %d", &num, &rotations);
> ```

the last argument of *scanf* must be a pointer to an *int* (format is `%d`) but you give the address of a *char*, the behavior is undefined. Use an *int* for *rotations* for the format `%d`

---

In `my_rotate` *b* is a *char* and you do `if(b < 0)`, the result depends if the *char* are signed or not, type *n* with *signed char* if you expect a char to be signed

---

If *rotations* is an *int* and *b* a *signed char* :

- 44795 (1010111011111011) and -3 produce 30175 being 111010111011111
- 44795 (1010111011111011) and 3 produce 30685 being 111011111011101

as you expected.

Note for me an *unsigned short* is on 16 bits, of course the result is not the same if *short* are on a different number of bit.

Comment: What do i have to type to use the char as signed char?

Comment: @AlbertLeibnitz a _char_ can be signed or unsigned by default, your code suppose a _char_ is signed because of `if(b < 0)`, if your compiler consider a _char_ as _unsigned_ the test is always false. I replaced `char b` by `signed char b` for my tests

Comment: How its possible to get an input of a negative number using
`scanf("%c", &c);` ? It gets only the negative sign

Comment: @AlbertLeibnitz this is why I propose to let the format in the _scanf_ to `%d` and change the type of _rotations_ to _int_. Doing that I am sure to be able to read a negative value

Comment: i have to use char, its an exercise

Comment: @AlbertLeibnitz you cannot have `char rotations;` and the format `%d` for _scanf_ to read it. Note I use an _int_ just to read the value. In `my_rotate` _b_ is a _signed char_

Comment: What about `printf("%d", var);` ? var is a character.
Is it safe to print characters using %d?

Comment: @AlbertLeibnitz yes there is no problem because the _char_ is promoted to _int_ in the call. For the _scanf_ the problem occurs because you give the **address** of a _char_

Answer (score 0):

[@bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54963488/2410359) well explained a problem with input.

---

A rotation count may exceed `+/- bitsNum`, so a good first step is to limit the rotation count.

```
unsigned short my_rotate(unsigned short a, int b) {
   unsigned short bitsNum = sizeof(unsigned short) * 8;

   //add
   b %= bitsNum;

   ....
```

Highly portable code  would not use `bitsNum` as that is derived by the *size* of `unsigned short` (and assumes 8 bits/`char`) and an `unsigned short` could have padding bits.  Certainly this is more of a rare  machine concern.  Code should derive the bit width based on `USHRT_MAX` instead.